# Android cyrillic json

Tags: android, json, parsing, cyrillic

Im new in android development and I'm working on a small app right now.

I have JSON file that I use to make a list. Everything was fine with the app until I changed the JSON file. I need to use cyrillic alphabet. The problem is that when I run the app nothing shows and log is full of warnings and other stuff (no errors).

Here is a sample of my JSON:

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name":"Вангел",
      "hometown":"Битола"
    },
    ....
  ]
}
```

I've been searching on internet about this for 2 days and no answer. I'm using UTF-8 encoding by the way.

Comment: Can you post those warnings you are getting? Also, include the code you are using.

Comment: yea, give us some more info and: are you sure your JSON is correct and doesn't have any invalid commas, etc.?! Also important to know: which library is used for parsing? gson?

Comment: I got it...I've change the Encoding to UTF-8 in every place where it is possible...sorry for the late answer. At first it didn't work, but then some magic happened and it worked.